# plot bar and fill according to % correct

Tags: matlab, plot

I have n sensors. For every round 1 to N I am going to see how many sensors are alive and draw it as a bar or box. the height of the bar will be the number of sensors.

Also

From the n sensor x will be correct y different by 10 values and z wrong. Can we display that by % of the bar colored according to x y z (green blue red for example)?

in addition if the mean value is correct i want the contour of the bar to be blue else to be red.

Comment: See the "stacked bar plot" example: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35272-matlab-plot-gallery-stacked-bar-chart/content/html/Stacked_Bar_Chart.html

Comment: tried to do the same but was not able @John Colby

Comment: What part are you getting stuck at? Some example code/data would help.

Comment: I am getting the results in a loop and bar is in the loop too maybe I need to store the data and plot outside the loop will post some data tooo thanks @John Colby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was to save the data in array and then plot